# Google suggestions result empty data parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a search bar for google on my website and i've got problems with the suggestions.

The code shows the request to suggestqueries.google.com but i'm not getting any data in the data parameter.

```
$.get('http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search', {
        q: searchStr,
        client: "chrome"
    }, function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
```

I've checked with wireshark. There is a response from google with the suggestions like `["hey"["hey siri", "hey ...` as http message. How can I get this response from inside my code to use it as suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `done(...)`:

```
$.get('http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search', {
    q: searchStr,
    client: "chrome"
}).done(function(data) { 
    //do something with the data
});
```

Comment: I've applied this to both, this issue and another request of my Web Application and it only worked for the other one, so my guess is this is related how suggestqueries respond on requests. I found a way around using $.getJSON() with a callback that uses also the data parameter, but the same function in the code above won't work